# Phonegap Android: keyboard overlap screen want to push screen up but it doesnot

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

Phonegap Android: keyboard overlap screen instead of pushing application up in device. I want to see the input box so that I can see what I am typing.

We have tried following solutions:

1. config.xml : `<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`
2. AndroidMainfest.xml - `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

But it doesnot work.

Please help me what to do. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

android xml path: app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

changes:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_pgb_config.md.html, if you are using a remote cli or PhoneGap Build,  try this into config.xml

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Otherwise, as a (ugly) workaround, you could scroll the view so the input having the focus is at the top of it.

Comment: Thanks DavidC I edit it in wrong config.xml file. Actually I need to change in right xml file and the path for android xml is app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml.